# CDH4 : Add new node to existing cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I have successfully created hadoop cluster with CDH4 on ubuntu . I have created this with one master(master) and one slave(slave1) . Now I want to add one more cluster . For this I just cloned slave2 and updated hosts and ssh accordingly . Then I updated conf/slaves file with all datanode dns names in all nodes and restarted everything . But it's not detecting the new datanode instead it only shows the old one that is slave1 not slave2 . Can anyone please help me on this ?
I have used cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2009755, you need to create a master and slave file only in the master. And in configuration files in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop, make necessary changes to the URI pointing to the master node.
NOTE: Try to format the namenode and delete the tmp files (usually /tmp/*) but if you changed it in `core-site.xml`, format that directory in all nodes and start all the daemons, it worked for me.

Comment: I made it work finally .I formatted namenode and recreated data node storage directories and restarted everything and it worked . But in production I can't format NN .

Comment: @user2009755, what is the error when you try to format the namenode? please post it.

Comment: formatting always works for me ...my issue was just to add a new node which was finally resolved ..

Answer (score 0):

There is so many reasons,

Have you change the dfs.replication value to 3 in conf/hdfs-site.xml??

check on master with cammands **hduser@master:~$ ssh slave** it should be show the slave terminal if not then execute this cammand -**hduser@master:~$ ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slave**

for fully understand see this link

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/